# Extracting symbol names from nm output

Tags: sed, posix, nm

I'd like to use `nm -P -g` symbol names to generate a `.c` file. however I'm not sure how to extract those symbol names.

Reading https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html says:

> The format given in nm STDOUT uses <space> characters between the fields, which may be any number of <blank> characters required to align the columns.

I'm not sure how to interpret this - should my regex be `^[^ ]+_mkdocs[ ]` [note: workaround for stackoverflow's wonky code formatting] or something else? I want the result to be whatever symbol name I extracted concatenated with `(&doc);`

e.g.

```
foo_mkdocs T 0 0
```

should become

```
foo_mkdocs(&doc);
```

but I'm unsure if I'm understanding nm's output format specification correctly.

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 done